# How can I pass multiple values to a function when only some variables need more than one - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a function that will create a new column based on criteria from other columns.  The function works fine when i pass only one variable, but when two are needed it does not work.  A sample of what I am trying to do is:

```
### create a function called name

def name(ID, NAME):
    if (ID == 1 ):
        return "First"
   elif (ID == 2):
        return "Second"
   elif (ID == 3):
       return "Third"
   elif (ID == 4 and NAME = “Four” ):
        return "Fourth"

### apply function to dataset and view results

dataset["NAME"].apply(name).head(100)
```

Most of my new column values can be obtained by looking at only one variable, but a few require two.  Can anyone provide direction on how I might accomplish this in python?  In R I used the case_when function in dplyr but  I dont seem to find that case statements are supported in python

Comment: You have a few syntax errors. `NAME = “Four”` should be `NAME == "Four"`. Notice two equals signs for equality comparison and normal double quotes, not "fancy" quotes, around `Four`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify your function and create a toy data

```
def name(ID, NAME):
    if ID == 1 :
        return "First"
    elif ID == 2:
        return "Second"
    elif ID == 3:
        return "Third"
    elif ID == 4 and NAME == "Four" :
        return "Fourth"

dataset=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,4],'NAME':[1,2,3,4,'Four']})

dataset.apply(lambda x: name(x['ID'], x['NAME']), axis=1)

Out[741]: 
0     First
1    Second
2     Third
3      None# return None cause , it did not match all the condition 
4    Fourth
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, I am marking this as the accepted answer.  Both solutions work, but this was pretty straight forward for me to apply to my project!

Comment: @Brad_J yw~ :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the whole row of a dataframe to a function with axis=1 parameter in apply and then you access parts of the rows in your function like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def nameme(row):
    if (row.ID == 1 ):
        return "First"
    elif (row.ID == 2):
        return "Second"
    elif (row.ID == 3):
       return "Third"
    elif (row.ID == 4 and row.Name == 'Four' ):
        return "Fourth"


dataset = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,1,2,3,4,5],'Name':['Four']*6})

dataset.apply(nameme, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0      None
1     First
2    Second
3     Third
4    Fourth
5      None
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks - I was able to modify this and get it to work on my dataset.  i appreciate your time and your comments!

Answer (score 0):

You have two good answers there from Wen and Scott Boston.  Here's my take on it that handles cases where your `DataFrame` might not necessarily have the column you're looking for.  So instead of throwing you an error it'll just return `None` as a result:

```
def name(df):
    ID = df.get('ID')  # returns None if your DataFrame doesn't contain an 'ID' column
    NAME = df.get('NAME')  # returns None if your DataFrame doesn't contain a 'NAME' column
    if (ID == 1 ):
        return "First"
    elif (ID == 2):
        return "Second"
    elif (ID == 3):
        return "Third"
    elif (ID == 4 and NAME == "Four" ):
        return "Fourth"

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5], 'NAME':[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Four', 'Four']})
data['RESULT'] = data.apply(name, axis=1)

#    ID  NAME  RESULT
# 0   1     1   First
# 1   2     2  Second
# 2   3     3   Third
# 3   4     4    None
# 4   4  Four  Fourth
# 5   5  Four    None
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for your comment.  I see how this can be helpful.  i am just learning Python so this is helpful to me.